# iOS remote provisioning?

Tags: xcode, ios

Right now, the only way I can test my app on a device is to physically plug it into my laptop, and build/deploy from xcode directly to it.  Is there any way I can do this remotely without physically plugging the device into my mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To second what Moshe and Clay said, you can use a number of services that provide over-the-air distribution.

TestFlight is a fully-featured service that provides team and beta campaign management in addition to over-the-air distribution. It is a hosted service so there is no setup.

Hockey is similar in its execution and does a great job as well. I haven't used Hockey, so I can't speak to it's full feature set.

Full disclosure, I am one of the mobile devs on TestFlight.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install an app without physically connecting it to your mac until it is under development phase.Second way is to create a build and then install that build in your iPhone through iTunes,so Xcode is not required.But this is generally used to show intermediate builds to Client.So you will have to continue following the same process my friend...

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question and the unfortunate answer is that this is really not possible. You can try Ad Hoc builds as an alternative or a service called [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to TestFlight is [Hockey](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/Hockey), but it's more work. I use TestFlight, and I like it. A friend uses Hockey with good results.